# Spring Boot with xml and json with jackson only returns xml

Tags: json, xml, spring, jackson

Let me thank you in advance for your help!

I have a weird behaviour in an spring boot application. Let me explain it for you:

I'm wrapping some legacy web services (custom xml messages) with some nice rest-json services (via spring-mvc and spring boot and using jackson for serializing stuff)

In order to communicate with the legacy systems, I have created a custom XmlMapper, serializers and deserializers.

And finally, I have created an httpclientconfig, in order to define some http connection properties...

But after starting the app and trying to visit any endpoint (actuator ones for example), the app only returns xml. Event swagger endpoints return xml (what makes swagger-ui going nuts.

These are some of the classes:

```
    @Configuration
    public class HttpClientConfig {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClientConfig.class);
        @Value(value = "${app.http.client.max_total_connections}")
        public String MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS;

        @Value(value = "${app.http.client.max_connections_per_route}")
        public String MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE;

        @Value(value = "${app.http.client.connection_timeout_milliseconds}")
        public String CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;

        @Bean
        public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
            return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
        }
        @Autowired 
        private XmlMapper xmlMapper;
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory());
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

            for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
                if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
                }
                if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
                    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) converter;              
                    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(xmlMapper);
                }
            }

            logger.debug("restTemplate object created====================================");
            return restTemplate;
        }

        @Bean
        public HttpClient httpClient() {
            HttpClient httpClient = null;
            try {
                HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

                // disable SSL check
                SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).build();
                httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
                // don't check Hostnames
                HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
                Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                        .register("https", sslSocketFactory).build();

                PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
                connMgr.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS));
                connMgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(Integer.parseInt(MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE));
                RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS)).build();

                httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(config);
                httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connMgr);

                // to avoid nohttpresponse
                httpClientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount,
                            org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext context) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Excption creating HttpClient: ", e);
            }
            return httpClient;
        }
    }
```

And the xml mapper

```
    @Configuration
    public class XmlMapperConfig{

        @Bean
        public XmlMapper getXmlMapper() {
            XmlMapper mapper=new XmlMapper();       
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();       
            module.addSerializer(CafRequestObject.class, new CafRequestObjectSerializer());
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            mapper.registerModule(module);      
            mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
            CafXmlSerializationProvider cafXmlProvider=new CafXmlSerializationProvider(new XmlRootNameLookup());        

            mapper.setSerializerProvider(cafXmlProvider);
            return mapper;
        }


    }
```

I call to findAndregisterModules, because I am also developing some libraries which provides additional serializers for services (modularized stuff)

I'm completely lost with this. Any help would be much appreciated...

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry
                .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
            registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Having the same issue and adding `configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);` doesn't seem to help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RestTemplate` bean to generate the object via `new RestTemplateBuilder.build()` instead of `new RestTemplate`. That should be all.

Yes, it feels awkward and like hidden magic (which one is used to when using Spring Boot i guess), but it seems directly using `RestTemplate` is not the correct way as intended by the Spring Boot creators.

More detailed explanation [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315954/1246547).